# Showing after hiding window removes all content

Tags: user-interface, go, andlabs-ui

I am using following code which produces a main window with a button to open other window.  I want to be able to repeatedly hide and show other window. Closing main window should exit the program:

```
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")

func main() {
    ui.Main(makeAllWins)
}

var mainWindow *ui.Window
var otherWindow *ui.Window

func makeAllWins(){
    makeMainWin()
    makeOtherWin()
    mainWindow.Show()
}
func makeMainWin(){
    var otherButton = ui.NewButton("Other module")
    otherButton.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) { otherWindow.Show() })
    var box = ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Select module"), false)
    box.Append(otherButton, false)
    mainWindow = ui.NewWindow("Hello", 200, 100, false)
    mainWindow.SetChild(box)
    mainWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true   } )
}
func makeOtherWin(){
    var box = ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("label1"), false)
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("label2"), false)
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("label3"), false)
    otherWindow = ui.NewWindow("Other", 200, 100, false)
    otherWindow.SetChild(box)
    otherWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { otherWindow.Hide(); return true } )  // I THINK PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE
}
```

However, when I show the other window after hiding it once, all the labels are gone. On repeating, the program crashes with following error:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x67fb0a pc=0x67fb0a]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Returning `true` from your `OnClosing` function argument destroys the window on closing, does it not? Try returning `false` instead.

Comment: Yes, it works on returning `false`. If you enter this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
otherWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { otherWindow.Hide(); return true } )
```

you should be returning `false` instead of `true`. As it is, the window is getting destroyed when you close it, leading to the segmentation fault when you try to reference it later.

Per [the documentation comments](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/master/window.go#L70):

> OnClosing registers f to be run when the user clicks the Window's
>   close button. Only one function can be registered at a time.  If f
>   returns true, the window is destroyed with the Destroy method.  If f
>   returns false, or if OnClosing is never called, the window is not
>   destroyed and is kept visible.